# Open modal box by jQuery onchange of select option

Tags: jquery

How can I open a model box by jQuery on change of select option?

Answer (score 1):

You can sent a listener for the select option change

checkout the example here  http://jsfiddle.net/N4EZf/2/

html

```
<select id="selectMe">
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
</select>
```

jquery

```
alert('ready');
$('#selectMe').change(function() {
    alert('Call modal function');
});
```

​

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you mean by "modal box" (or "model box" in the question).

If you're talking about a [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/), this should do it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // Set the element as a dialog
    $('div#modalDialog').dialog({
        modal: true,
        autoOpen: false
    });

    // Set the dialog to open when mySelect changes
    $('select#mySelect').change(function() {
        $('#modalDialog').dialog('open');
    });

});
```

This will, when the DOM has loaded, configure a `div` element with the `id` "modalDialog" to be a modal dialog and set a listener on the `change` event of a `select` element with the id "mySelect" to open the dialog.

Answer (score 0):

```
onchange = "$('#dialogboxname').dialog('open');"
```

add the onchange attribute like above^